# What to do if an accepted answer is not an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I wanted to ask a question about something and firstly searched and found a [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15953/can-i-allow-people-to-use-their-fb-twitter-or-g-accounts-to-post-comments-in-m). But there is a problem: the accepted answer is **not** an answer that meets the needs. I didn't understand how the OP accepted it but anyway I asked [my own question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170128/how-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-comment-with-their-twitter-facebook-or-g-accou).

Then, my question was marked as **duplicate** and closed.

**Now, what should I do?** I commented on the other question and asked to the OP "*you accepted this as an answer but does it really fit your needs?*" but he didn't reply my comment.

I'm recommend to place a bounty on it but I think it's not a good way because there is an *accepted answer*.

And also the "not" answer suggests a module and the module is for Drupal 6 only. Then I tagged the question with `6` because no Drupal 7 version is exist. But then the `6` tag removed, didn't understand why.

My question was tagged with `7` and because the solutions can be differ for 6 and 7; why my question is still considered as **duplicate**?

Answer (score 2):

An "answer" is something that attempts to provide a solution to the posed problem.

As such, the accepted post on that question *is* an answer; you just don't agree with the content.

Downvote, move on. Nothing more to do or see.

The `6` tag that you added was removed, because the original question wasn't asking for an answer for a specific version. You changed the intent of the original question, so the change was rolled back.

Your question is considered a duplicate because, and I don't mean to be patronising, the questions are duplicates of one another.

As you've already hinted at: if you want a different or better answer to an existing question, please put a bounty on it. That's the only mechanism we have available for getting new answers to duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

The question you asked is a duplicate of the question already asked; in fact both the questions have the same requirements. The fact the OP accepted that answer could probably mean the OP was convinced there was not a module with the requirements they had.

An accepted answer doesn't stop other users from answering the question. If you really need an answer for that question, you can offer a bounty for the old question. In this way, it will get new eyes on it, and the bounty will be an incentive to answer.
As alternative, you could make the question very different from the old one; for example, state that the suggested module doesn't suit your use case, or add more details that would help users to suggest you a module that you could use.

Since the recent changes in the closing reasons, I would also suggest you to show what modules you found on drupal.org and why you discarded them.